# Easiest way to override PosixPath in hydra

Tags: python, fb-hydra, omegaconf

Consider the following yaml file for hydra config:

```yaml
a:  
    b: !!python/object/apply:pathlib.PosixPath
    - /my/path/to/dir
```

How would I override `a.b` so that is stays `PosixPath` after providing a new path?

Running

```bash
python my_app.py ++a.b=/a/new/path
```

overrides `a.b` but it's obiously a string. Looking for a solution that not only works but preferably does not require a user to re-enter constructor information.

Comment: So you have to specify the type in the config file, but you shouldn't from the command line? Seems like whatever consumes both should be responsible for converting an `a.b` string value to a path.

Answer (score 0):

One way I found is this:

```yaml
a:  
    b: 
      filepath: ???
      _target_: pathlib.Path 
      _args_: 
        - ${a.b.filepath}
```

Then overriding is via

```bash
python ++a.b.filepath=/a/new/path
```

Here, I'm using [instantiate API](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/instantiate_objects/overview/), the `_target_` is a target class of object (pathlib is natively supported), and since constructor signature is `pathlib.Path(*pathsegments)` we need a list, if we would provide just a string, each letter would be a single segment.

For those wondering why `filepath` is required here:

1. If we would supply value directly to `a.b` the instantiation is skipped (so it's still `str`, the same case as in the question)
2. It might be skipped and `_args_` might be used directly but it is not verbose for end-user (`python ++a.b._args_=/a/new/path`)